# javascript array efficiency

Tags: javascript, vector

In order to pinpoint objects with very erratic mouse coordinates I jumped over a step or two and luxuriously just used a wide span of vector indexes. But does this mean I am allocating space for 6000 or so values in my vector? Does it slow something down? Or is it OK?

```
// ---- starting position ---- 
    mouse.x        = screen.w / 2; 
    mouse.xd       = mouse.x; 
    camera.x       = scene.startX || 0; 
    camera.z       = scene.startZ || 0; 
    camera.targetX = scene.targetX || 0; 
    camera.targetZ = scene.targetZ || 0; 
    var picIndex=new Array(1,101,2101,4101,4401,5401,6401,6301,2301,2001); // pics position in room
    var myPics=new Array(); // 
    myPics[1]="This is picture 1"; // 
    myPics[101]="This is picture 2";
    myPics[2101]="This is picture 3";
    myPics[4101]="This is picture 4";
    myPics[4401]="This is picture 5";
    myPics[5401]="This is picture 6";
    myPics[6401]="This is picture 7";
    myPics[6301]="This is picture 8";
    myPics[2301]="This is picture 9";
    myPics[2001]="This is picture 10";


    // then show picture identification


    setInterval(function () { 
    uniqueID = (camera.targetZ*2)+camera.targetX+3201;
    showInfo = document.getElementById('dynamic_info');
    showInfo.innerHTML = myPics[uniqueID] ; 
        //document.getElementById('dynamic_info2').innerHTML =   camera.targetX ;
        //document.getElementById('dynamic_info3').innerHTML = uniqueID; 
        //document.getElementById('dynamic_info4').innerHTML = camera.z ;
        //document.getElementById('npoly').innerHTML = npoly * 2; 
        //fps = 0; 
        //npoly = 0; 
    }, 500); // update every 0.5 seconds
```

Comment: The proof is in the pudding. Generally speaking, sampling constant user input at reasonable intervals is an acceptable practice, but the answer as to whether or not you should do it lies in what happens when you try it.

Comment: The sampling hasn't been a problem so far - I was just worried about the array[link](http://mindprints.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is treated as a sparse Array. [More details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2008/04/08/performance-optimization-of-arrays-part-ii.aspx)